# Helm Install/Upgrade set value on CLI in every element in array or by value

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a vendor Chart I am working with that boils down to this:

```yaml
vendor:
  tier:
    - name: tier1
      valueToSet: TBD

    - name: tier2
      valueToSet: TBD

    - name: tier3
      valueToSet: TBD
      customValueOnlyInThisTier: TBD

    - name: tierN
      valueToSet: TBD
```

The data for `valueToSet` and `customValueOnlyInThisTier` needs to be pull dynamically every time we run an install/upgrade due to vendor limitations. What I would like to do is avoid having to edit the file itself every time we run an upgrade (it is rather gigantic).

1. Is there a means to add the value to every element in the array using `--set` parameter to the [upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) call?
2. Is there a way to use a selector for the array to set `customValueOnlyInThisTier` using a syntax like `--set vendor.tier[?name="tier3"].customValueOnlyInThisTier=TESTING`?

### Temporary Workaround

I figured I can do something like this:

```bash
# something here that generates PREPEND.yaml
mv values.yaml values.yaml.bak
cat PREPEND.yaml values.yaml.bak > values.yaml
```

In the generated `PREPEND.yaml` file I can add something like:

```yaml
Reference1: &SomeTag1 VALUE_HERE
Reference2: &SomeTag2 VALUE_HERE
```

Then I can reference that data in the `values.yaml` this way:

```yaml
vendor:
  tier:
    - name: tier1
      valueToSet: *SomeTag1
```

It's hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

values.yaml

```yaml
vendor:
  tier:
    - name: tier1
      valueToSet: TBD
    - name: tier2
      valueToSet: TBD
    - name: tier3
      valueToSet: TBD
      customValueOnlyInThisTier: TBD
    - name: tierN
      valueToSet: TBD
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    {{- toYaml $.Values.vendor | nindent 4 }}
```

1. cmd :

```bash
helm template --debug test . \
    --set 'vendor.tier[0].name=tier1' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[0].valueToSet=TBD' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[1].name=tier2' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[1].valueToSet=TBD' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[2].name=tier3' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[2].valueToSet=TBD' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[2].customValueOnlyInThisTier=TESTING' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[3].name=tier4' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[3].valueToSet=TBD'
```

2. cmd :

```bash
helm template --debug test . \
    --set 'vendor.tier[0]={name:tier1,valueToSet:TBD}' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[1]={name:tier2,valueToSet:TBD}' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[2]={name:tier3,valueToSet:TBD,customValueOnlyInThisTier:TESTING}' \
    --set 'vendor.tier[3]={name:tier4,valueToSet:TBD}'
```

output

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    tier:
      - name:tier1
        valueToSet:TBD
      - name:tier2
        valueToSet:TBD
      - name:tier3
        valueToSet:TBD
        customValueOnlyInThisTier:TESTING
      - name:tier4
        valueToSet:TBD
```

Comment: So the problem here is that the vendor put in (and this is a literal count) 232 options for each of the pieces of the array. If I try to specify each entry for every piece of the array it is just unmanageable.